# A prime number checker (Multi numbers).py

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, mathematics

so obviously this SIMPLE code checks if the number is prime or not. I need to make it more advanced, easier to use, fewer lines or any improvement.

```
while True:
    lista = []
    try:
        num = int(input("Enter the amount of numbers: "))
        for i in range(0, num):
            value = int(input("Enter the numbers one by one: "))
            lista.append(value)
    except:
        print(''';-;
    Bruh, make sure you are entering numbers.''')
    for i in lista:
        if i <= 1:
            print("Duh,", i, "is not a primal number.")
            continue
        for j in range(2, i):
            if i % j == 0:
                print("Duh,", i, "is not a primal number.")
                break
        else:
            print("SMH,", i, "is a primal number obviously.")
```

Answer (score 3):

First improvement I see is mathematical: to check if a number `n` is prime, it's sufficient to verify that it's not divisible by any integer between 2 and `math.ceil(math.sqrt(n))` (don't forget to `import math` at the top of your file). That's going to make your program more efficient.

Another improvement would be to split the code that deals with getting the list of numbers `lista` from the user, and the code that finds if a single number is prime or not, into two separate functions that you call from the main `while True` loop. This will aid readability and code reuse.

A third improvement is to rename the variable `lista` to a more expressive name like `numbers` or `candidates` or something else.